# How can i display the number in such a format?

Tags: objective-c, ios

I am displaying a number in textfield. Which displays the number as "1234" but i want to display it as in format of "1,234" if i enter another large number which displays as "12345" but i want to display it as "12,345" if  i enter 123456 which has to display as "123,456" . How do I format this number in desired format?

```
-(void)clickDigit:(id)sender
{
    NSString * str = (NSString *)[sender currentTitle];
    NSLog(@"%@",currentVal);


    if([str isEqualToString:@"."]&& !([currentVal rangeOfString:@"."].location == NSNotFound) ) 
    {
        return;
    }
    if ([display.text isEqualToString:@"0"])
    {

        currentVal = str;
        [display setText:currentVal];
    }

    else if([currentVal isEqualToString:@"0"])
    {
        currentVal=str;
        [display setText:currentVal];

    }
    else
    {
        if ([display.text length] <= MAXLENGTH) 
        {
            currentVal = [currentVal stringByAppendingString:str];
            NSLog(@"%@",currentVal);
            [display setText:currentVal];
        }
        currentVal=display.text;
    }
}
```

This is the code i am using to display the number in textfield.

---

**EDIT:** I Changed my code into the following but still don't get the number correctly formatted:

```
if ([display.text length] <= MAXLENGTH) {
    currentVal = [currentVal stringByAppendingString:str];
    NSNumberFormatter * myNumFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
    [myNumFormatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle]; 
    NSNumber *tempNum = [myNumFormatter numberFromString:currentVal];
    NSLog(@"My number is %@",tempNum);
    [display setText:[tempNum stringValue]];
    currentVal=display.text;
}
```

Comment: Check out the question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5406366/formatting-a-number-to-show-commas-and-or-dollar-sign - the accepted answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/5407103/928098 looks like it'll solve your problem

Comment: I think OP doesn't need a dollar sign in the displayed string as in the answer you linked to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
int myInt = 12345;
NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
formatter.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle;
NSNumber *number = [NSNumber numberWithInt:myInt];
NSLog(@"%@", [formatter stringFromNumber:number]); // 12,345
```

**Edit**

You didn't implement this correctly, the key is to obtain the string representation of the number using `[formatter stringFromNumber:number]`, but you didn't do that. So change your code into:

```
currentVal = [currentVal stringByAppendingString:str];
NSNumberFormatter * myNumFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[myNumFormatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle]; 
NSNumber *tempNum = [myNumFormatter numberFromString:currentVal];
NSLog(@"My number is %@",tempNum);
[display setText:[myNumFormatter stringFromNumber:tempNum]]; // Change this line
currentVal=display.text;
NSLog(@"My formatted number is %@", currentVal);
```

Comment: Its not giving the desired result .. still it displays as 12345 not getting comma as a separator. I think we have to add some string separator to it

Comment: @Karthikeya - This is strange, can you post your updated code?

Comment: yeah it works fine for first time like if i enter 1234 giving result as 1,234 but second time current value is becoming null

Comment: @sch Sorry about that -- you're right that NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle will do the right thing. I expect it's better in general to do that, since it probably does use the correct settings for the user's region.

Comment: @Karthikeya - If it gives you `null` I guess the problem is that `currentVal` is not correctly formatted. After all, you add some digits to the original number so `1,234` will become `1,2345` which is not parsed correctly.

Comment: @sch -Thank you , problem solved, I had to remove last but one line. current value will be formatted as we want

Answer (score 0):

First, read through the list of methods on the [NSNumberFormatter reference page](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumberFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html). After doing that, you'll probably realize that you need to use the `-setHasThousandSeparators:` method to turn on the thousand separators feature. You can also use the `-setThousandSeparator:` method to set a custom separator, though you probably won't need to do that.