# How to get commas in my number ie 24,532,664 using UILabel?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uilabel

How to set up the display to show commas: 24,532,664 as opposed to 24532664?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using [NSNumberFormatter](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfNumberFormatting10_4.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002368-SW1).

**Listing 1**

```
NSNumberFormatter *numberFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[numberFormatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
NSNumber *myNumber = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:122344];
NSString *formattedNumberString = [numberFormatter stringFromNumber:myNumber];
[numberFormatter release];  // if you aren't using ARC.
NSLog(@"formattedNumberString: %@", formattedNumberString);
// Output for locale en_US: "formattedNumberString: formattedNumberString: 122,344"
```

Answer (score 3):

You may use `-[NSString initWithFormat:locale:]`.

```
NSLocale *locale = [NSLocale currentLocale]; // always use the user's locale
NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%d" locale:locale, 24532664];
```

If the commas are mandatory, you may choose a specific locale (`en_US`), in order to always get the same result. But that's not a good idea if the string is meant to be displayed to the user.

```
NSLocale *locale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"];
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use NSNumberFormatter for this.

E.g. [Formatting a number to show commas and/or dollar sign](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5406366/formatting-a-number-to-show-commas-and-or-dollar-sign)

Don't forget to clean up after!!!